# Is "Saltadilla" a randomly made-up word or does it have a genuine Spanish meaning?

Tags: traducción, terminología

*The Powerpuff Girls*, a Cartoon Network cartoon originally running from 1998 to 2005, is set in a city called Townsville. In the Spanish version of the show—traducido al español latino como *Las chicas superpoderosas*, y en España como *Las supernenas*—Townsville is known, instead, as Saltadilla.

When I discovered this, I was sure that the name would reveal some inherent meaning, like the English "Townsville" does. Townsville is itself a rather funny word because it signifies something like "Town's Town" (combining the more Germanic word "town" with the more Latinate root *villa*, which occurs in a number of modern languages descended from Latin, including Spanish).

I asked a couple of native speakers of Spanish (one from Venezuela and the other from Argentina) if "Saltadilla" has a similar clever basis, but, according to them, and from what I've been able to find by searching online, it's essentially a meaningless, made-up word.

One of the aforementioned hispanohablantes had the same thought that I did, noting that the first half of the word, *Salta*, appears to be based on *saltar*, "to jump," but then this seems to go nowhere when attached to the *-dilla*.

Mi español todavía es algo básico, así que tal vez haya un juego de palabras inteligente, o algo así, escondiéndose de mí de allí. ¿O no es así? Is it essentially a nonsense-word?

Comment: I cannot make any sense out of the word "Saltadilla" either, and I agree that the ending "-dilla" obscures any reasonable relation to "saltar". I also cannot find any explanation online...

Comment: There are a number of place names that begin with *Sal*.  I'm thinking of Salinas, California,  Saltillo, Mexico, or Salta, Argentina.  Possibly even Salzburg, Austria.  In some of these, the reference is to salt.

Comment: @wimi : I'm wondering whether it gets any better if one thinks about it in terms of the imperative form _Saltad_ , to then end it in _-illa_ . I'm assuming the answer is "Not really," but that was my other thought about how to break the word up.

Comment: @WalterMitty : Hmmm... Saltillo comes quite close. I hadn't thought about the possibility of _Sal_ + _tadilla_ . I looked up "tadilla", but didn't find anything particularly illuminating on that. The "salt" angle would've been a great reference if it was one of the ingredients used to create las chicas superpoderosas, but, according to the TV show, they were made from _azúcar, especias y todo lo bonito._

Comment: Saltillo means small waterfall.  That's where Saltillo, Mexico gets it, iirc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo soy de México y desde niño cada vez que escuchábamos el nombre de la ciudad "Saltadilla" no reconocíamos la palabra. No sabía que en España también usaron esa palabra. De hecho yo pensaba que era algo así como "Santavilla". Y en internet no hay nada que nos diga sobre  de dónde sacaron esa palabra los traductores.

Yo supongo que Saltadilla viene de salto pero con uno de los sufijos usados en español. El diminutivo de salto sería saltito, y el diminutivo terminado en "illo" o "illa" se refiere a un diminutivo más despectivo, como restando valor o importancia a la acción o al objeto o sujeto,  o también puede tener algún valor afectivo pero solo en algunos casos. En este caso sería saltito, o para usar el diminutivo con el sufijo illo seria saltillo.

Un ejemplo sería: me persiguió un perrito. Para restarle importancia al perro (quizá por ser de una raza pequeña y nada amenazante) diríamos: me persiguió un perrillo.

Ahora, en español tenemos las palabras que son masculinas y y otras que son femeninas. En ocasiones podemos transformar un verbo en un sustantivo y cambiarle su género. Y en México (quizá en otros países también) usamos mucho esto que acabo de mencionar y usamos el sufijo "ado", "ada", aunque ya exista un sustantivo.

Verbo: Limpiar. El sustantivo es Limpieza, nosotros lo cambiamos a limpiada. Ejemplo: ayer le dí una limpiada a la casa.
Ejemplo 2: Trapear. El sustantivo que creamos es Trapeada. Ejemplo: hoy le di una trapeada a la casa. Y para usar el sufijo diminutivo el ejemplo sería: ayer le di una "trapeadilla" a la casa.

Entonces desde ese punto de vista etimológico, yo podría decir, ayer le di una saltadilla a la cuerda (como decir: ayer salte la cuerda).

Es lo único con que puedo relacionar esa palabra, por lo demás no tiene lógica para nosotros los hispanohablantes en general.

Comment: Wow... Esto es bastante reflexivo. La explicación tiene mucho sentido.

Answer (score 1):

En España se conocen como Las Supernenas Z. La ciudad se llama Saltadilla donde viven los personajes de la serie. Si te refieres al nombre se le ha vinculado a los ojos, pues estos son muy "*saltones*" y sobresalen más de lo normal.

Comment: Oh, ¿en serio, de verdad? ¡Nunca hubiera imaginado tal conexión! Muchas gracias por intervenir. ¿Quizás tenga una fuente para esta idea? ¿Alguien relacionado con la creación del programa lo mencionó en algún lugar en línea o algo así?

Answer (score 1):

Mi teoria es que hace referencia a,
Salton = algo que sobre sale.
E illa = algo que se usa para hacer diminutivo una palabra.
Tal vez haciendo referencia a qué la suciedad resalta poco o que es poco interesant

Comment: ¿La *suciedad* resalta poco?